# Epilog relative to frame

Tags: plotting

I need to put letters (A), (B) etc at right top corner of different framed plots joined using Show in one big figure. So at all plots letters should be placed at the same distance from top and left axis of the frame:

[image]

I tried to use Epilog but the axis scales of all plots are different, so it does not work well. Is it possible to solve this issue in simple way?

Comment: something like `Legended[BarChart[RandomInteger[10, 10], 
  ImageMargins -> {{5, 0}, {0, 0}}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 600], 
 Placed[Style["A", 24, "Panel", 
   Background -> Transparent], {{Right, Top}}]]`?

Comment: @kglr Almost! It is too close to the corner. Is it possible to get more space from top and right?

Comment: you can use `{Scaled[.95], Scaled[.9]}` for the top plot and `{Scaled[.9], Scaled[.9]}` for the bottom ones in place of `{{Right, Top}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are no input graphs, I will be using the following three simulated graphs

[image]

In order to incorporate a letter indicator for each graph I will be using `Epilog` along with [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) with *scaled* coordinates (see [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html)).

Evaluating

```
Grid[
 Through[
   {{First[#], SpanFromLeft} &, Rest}[
     MapThread[plot, Transpose@args]
   ]
  ]
]
```

produces

[image]

---

**code**

```
(* functions used for display purposes *)
funcs = {Cos[#] - Sin[3 # - 2] &, 
  -12.1 #^3 + 10 #^2 - 3.02 # + 12 &, 
  2.1 #^4 - 3.2 #^3 + #^2 - 3.02 # + 12 &};

(* ranges used for plotting functions *)
rng = {{-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {-4.1, 3.2}, {-2.7, 3.1}};

(* size of each plot - relative size differences are 
   important in order to produce the effect present in the question *)
sz = {Large, Medium, Medium};

(* the symbols used to index the different plots *)
sym = {A, B, C};

(* combination of expressions to be used as input -  see below *)
args = Transpose[{funcs, rng, sz, sym}];

plot[f_, rng_, sz_, sym_] := Module[{x},
  Plot[
   f[x],
   Flatten[{x, rng}],
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> False,
   ImageSize -> sz,
   Epilog -> {Inset[Style[sym, Bold, 22], Scaled[{0.9, 0.85}]]}
   ]
  ]
```

***Edit***

Alternatively, the rhs of the `Epilog` option can be modified to `Inset[Style[sym, Bold, 22], Offset[{-30, -30}, Scaled[{1, 1}]]]` as suggested in the comments by *@Carl Woll*. Using `Offset` with `Scaled` provides better control over the position of the label.

Comment: A small tweak. I would use `Offset` with `Scaled` instead. Something like: `Offset[{-30, -30}, Scaled[{1, 1}]]` instead of `Scaled[{0.9, 0.85}]` so that the position of the label is the same distance to the top right corner for each plot.